# How can I use "if/else" to modify a SymPy function?

Tags: python, sympy

I try to modify the image of the math function g = x³ with the "if/else" tool.

I need that when my function image is greater than 0 the result remains the same, but if the image is something else I want the image to become the result of 1/g.

For the moment I tried this:

```
from sympy import * 
from sympy.abc import x

g = x**3
 
if g > 0:   
   g = g 
else:   
   g = 1/g
 
plot(g)
```

But it answers me this:

```
File "c:/Users/Anticrate/Desktop/PYTHON Sauvegardes/tes7.py", line 8, in <module>
    if g > 0:
  File "C:\Users\Anticrate\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 398, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

Comment: x is the unknow value of the g function

Comment: I'm not familiar with the sympy module, but you'll have a n undefined value when `g == 0`, as you can't do `1/0`

Comment: ok. But you think this is why I can't plot the rest of the function ?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with that package. It's just an observation on the mathematical function

Comment: It's not really clear to me what result you are expecting. ``g`` is a function *of* a parameter ``x``. It is not an integer value and thus cannot be larger, equal nor smaller than 0. Did you intend to define a second function also called ``g`` that has the same value as ``g`` wherever ``g`` is positive, and the inverse of ``g`` wherever ``g`` is negative?

Comment: I spoke about the 'image" of the function g that is all integers values that are used plot the curve of the function (I think). This is more or less what you say, I need a new function.

Comment: You can't use a `sympy` expression like `g>0` in a python `if/else`.  `if/else` is meant for simple `True/False` actions.  It can't define a new `sympy` expression that depends on the `x` symbol.  I haven't seen this error in `sympy` before, but we see similar `ambiguity` errors all the time in `numpy` and `pandas`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Piecewise` to create a function that is defined based on symbolic conditionals:

```
In [1]: from sympy import Symbol, Piecewise, plot

In [2]: x = Symbol('x')

In [3]: g = Piecewise((x**3, x>0), (1/x**3, True))

In [4]: g
Out[4]: 
⎧ 3           
⎪x   for x > 0
⎪             
⎨1            
⎪──  otherwise
⎪ 3           
⎩x            

In [6]: plot(g, ylim=(-10, 10))
Out[6]: <sympy.plotting.plot.Plot at 0x7f89c4ba61c0>
```

Comment: Looks correct for this example, but can you also make it depend on the *image* in general?

Comment: Sorry, I went too fast. I thought it worked but it doesn't. Because it's for x but not the image.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the image". Do you just want the condition to be `x**3 > 0`? If so then just change the arguments to `Piecewise`.